# Python how to check if database value is the same

Tags: python, database, firebase

Hello I have this firebase set up that is connected to a raspberry pi that speaks text according the firebase database.  I have the function running every 5 seconds, and I'd like to check if there is a new message.  I store the time of each message in the database, and the way i have it going now is that it's checking to see if the time is the same on new and old messages.

My two questions are:

Is there a better way to checking the messages time, to see if messages are new?

How can I fix this code so I am not getting a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'the_time' referenced before assignment"` error

Here is my code

```
import time
import subprocess
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('----', None)

message = firebase.get('/message', None)
name = firebase.get('/name', None)
the_time = firebase.get('the_time',None)
speak_message = message+" from "+ name

def showmessage():
        message=firebase.get('/message',None)
        name=firebase.get('/name',None)
        current_time = firebase.get('/the_time',None)
        speak_message=message+' from '+name

        #this is to set the audio jack on raspi
        subprocess.call(['amixer','cset','numid=3','1'])

        if current_time == the_time:
                #message is NOT new
                print 'message is NOT new'

        elif current_time != the_time:
                #message IS new
                #Shell script to run text-to-speech
                subprocess.call(['/home/pi/./speech.sh',speak_message])
                the_time = current_time


        time.sleep(5)
while True:
        showmessage()
```

Comment: can you write on the database? or is read only for that script?

Comment: @WissamYoussef I write to it via a webpage, but its read only from the script.

Comment: Okay never mind then :). I would have suggested to you to add another boolean variable in the DB . NEW(T/F). that way you can just fetch by NEW = True and then reset it to false before you speak_message. Which has the extra that you won't miss new messages if you get more than 1 in that 5 seconds gap. if you have more control over the infrastructure would check some message broker as well.  let me think about something within your restrains and I will give an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should works just fine, except one little, tiny mistake in this part:

```
elif current_time != the_time:
    #message IS new
    #Shell script to run text-to-speech
    subprocess.call(['/home/pi/./speech.sh',speak_message])
    the_time = current_time
```

You're assigning to `the_time`, which is a global variable. In your `showmessage` function, you didn't declare it, right?

To fix this, you must declare `the_time` to be a global variable.

```
def showmessage():
    global the_time
    #all other stuff
```

That's all you need to change :)
Hope this helps!